# How do I see the contents of process.env using bash?

Tags: node.js, windows, bash, command-line, environment-variables

Using the integrated Bash terminal in VS Code on Windows 10, I can access individual properties of the Node `process.env` object using `echo $PROPERTYNAME`, but I can't figure out how to list all of them.

```
$ process.env
bash: process.env: command not found
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Solved: start by typing `node` and pressing enter, then type `process.env` and press enter.

```
$ node
> process.env
{ ALLUSERSPROFILE: 'C:\\ProgramData',
  APPDATA: 'C:\\Users...,
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Pure node answer (on Linux at least)

`node --print 'process.env'`

`{ LC_PAPER: 'es_AR.UTF-8',
  LESSKEY: '/etc/lesskey.bin',
  MANPATH: '/usr/local/man:/usr/share/man',
  NNTPSERVER: 'news',
...
}`

Answer (score 9):

The bash way of listing environment variables is `env`:

```
$ env
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
TZ=US/Pacific
EDITOR=vim
PAGER=less
[...]
```